# Sorting tweets by timestamp in php

Tags: php, api, sorting, twitter

I'm putting together a project for class that has to do with aggregating tweets in succession to create a linear, crowdsourced story. I've currently got a semi-working program, with the issue that the program displays the most recent tweet first - what I need is to sort these tweets to have them displayed by timestamp, oldest to newest. Here's the code:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23tweetstoryproj&lang=en&rpp=100';
$jsontwitter = file_get_contents($url);
$twitter = json_decode($jsontwitter, true);

$twittertext = $twitter["results"];
foreach($twittertext as $text){
    $text = str_replace("#tweetstoryproj", "", $text);
    echo $text['text'].'';
}

?>
```

Thanks a lot for your help, and if you want to contribute to the story, tweet with the hashtag: #tweetstoryproj

Answer (score 3):

Simple! (He says) Just use [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

Add this line in before the foreach

```
$twittertext = array_reverse($twittertext);
```

Enjoy!

Alternative:
If the array becomes huge it may take longer to flip it then traverse it, so you could use a "[for](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)" loop and go backwards thusly.

```
for($i=$count($twittertext);$i>-1;$i--) //It's late that may miss the last or the first entry, have a fiddle!
{
  // echo here
}
```

Comment: For the sake of this being a school project, the first solution works wonders. Such an easy fix, I don't know why I didn't know that function. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey, there's a whole load of array functions, I don't feel bad for not knowing all of them, you shouldn't either (though it is fun to learn the others)